# How to pass an external object to rspec tests?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a series of RSpec tests - each one living in their own files - that all need a specific object to be ran (`shop`).

Since setting up the `shop` object is complicated, I want to have a master file that builds the `shop` object and then passes it to all the RSpec test files in turn. The idea is that those writing the test scripts do not need to know anything about the setup step.

I could not figure out how to bring something from the outside world into an rspec test case. I have tried variations around the lines of this:

file master.rb:

```
describe "Testing tests/some_test.rb" do
  before :all do
    @shop = some_complex_operations
  end
  load 'tests/some_test.rb'
end
```

file tests/some_test.rb:

```
describe 'Some feature' do
  it 'should know about @shop'
    expect(@shop).not_to be nil
  end
end
```

When I run `rspec master.rb` then some_test.rb fails.

I know what I outlined is probably a very wrong way to go about this, but I hope at least you get the idea.

How can I implement such a thing cleanly?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a [global hook](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks#define-before-and-after-blocks-in-configuration).

You can create a `spec_helper` and add there a before all global hook. For example:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) do
    @shop = "in case you need a fresh instance of shop each time"
  end
  config.before(:all) do
    @shop = "in case you need a single instance (i.e. you don't modify it)"
  end
end
```

Then you should require this helper from each of your specs. The `spec_helper` can store any global hooks as well as helpers, or other dependencies for your tests.

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing a test, it should test *one* thing. `shop` might be a very complex object, which many objects and methods interact with, but I should guess *none* of them are aware of the complexity of `shop` - each method is interested in some *aspect* of `shop`.

Therefore I suggest that instead of building a complex object for each test, make a `double` of it, make it *expect* what's relevant, and then simply *stub* the rest:

```
describe 'Some feature' do
  let(:shop) { double('shop').as_nil_object }
  let(:my_object) { MyClass.new(shop: shop) }


  it 'should do something awesome with shop' do
    expect(shop).to receive(:awesome_data).and_return(my_data: 'is_this')

    expect(my_object.do_something_awesome).to eq 'how awesome is_this?'
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand: how does this snippet become aware of the shop object? Besides, my test will only test one thing, maybe I explained improperly, shop can be thought of as being part of the context

Comment: I've amended my answer to use `let` for creating `shop`, and the context object...

Comment: OK, get it. But this doesn't really solve my issue. To be more specific: I have rspec test files that should be ran on different versions of the app. The shop object encapsulates the environment setup for a given version of the app. I would like to avoid making any reference to the version from within the test scripts, hence my attempt to "inject" shop from the outside into the test. In your proposal, there is still no "injection" of the object: the spec file builds it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - your tests should pass _no matter_ the app version? Or maybe the `shop` object contains the expected results? Or does it contain external services which are different between versions?

Comment: Yes the tests should pass no matter the app/shop version, and the shop does not contain the expected results.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused - so the `shop` object contains data about external services? It is a service itself? My suggestion is to build the tests in such a way that it wouldn't _matter_ what version the app is (encapsulate the external behavior in different tests, make sure that features do not rely on variables of a specific version, that sort of thing)...